# Get most occurring ManyToMany

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have an `ArchivedStream` model where a `Streamer` owns the stream. On these streams I have a `ManyToMany` field for the `Tag` model. What I'd like to do is find the top 5 tags across every `ArchivedStream` for a user.

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    aliases = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50), size=8,)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        to="self", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = "tags"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Streamer(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    profile_image_url = models.URLField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "streamers"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class ArchivedStream(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=24, default="not specified")
    stream_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    started_at = models.DateTimeField()
    ended_at = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    thumbnail_url = models.URLField()
    viewer_counts = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), default=[])
    language = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    stream_data = models.JSONField()
    streamer = models.ForeignKey(Streamer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, null=True, blank=True)
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "archived_streams"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I was thinking I could use `annotate()` in some capacity here, but I'm not sure how to nest these queries to find the occurrences of each `Tag`. Any ideas on how this aggregate would look?

Comment: So for a given `Streamer` you want to get the top `Tag`s over its related `ArchivedStream`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the `Tag`s over the `ArchivedStream`s of a `Streamer` with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Tag.objects.filter(
    archivedstream__streamer=my_streamer
).annotate(
    n=Count('archivedstream')
).order_by('-n')[:5]
```

This queryset will return the five most used `Tag`s for the *`my_streamer`*. The `Tag`s that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.n` that contains the number of times these have been used. In case of a *tie*, it is arbitrary which `Tag`s will return, so if for example there are six tags which have the maximum number of times these occur, five will be selected, but it is arbitrary what tag will be left out.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! It seems I was just complicating it more by trying to aggregate on the ArchivedStream rather than the Tag. This works great.